how to get xrm webapi records using react typescript
just want to ask what is the problem in the code when i pass this to my vscode, it says an error of: 'Xrm not defined' here is the code:
async function GetEnvironmentVariableValue(name: string): Promise<string | null> {
    
    let results = await Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("environmentvariabledefinition", `?$filter=schemaname eq '${name}'&$select=environmentvariabledefinitionid&$expand=environmentvariabledefinition_environmentvariablevalue($select=value)`);

    if (!results || !results.entities || results.entities.length < 1) return null;
    let variable = results.entities[0];
    if (!variable.environmentvariabledefinition_environmentvariablevalue || variable.environmentvariabledefinition_environmentvariablevalue.length < 1) return null;

    return variable.environmentvariabledefinition_environmentvariablevalue[0].value;
}

I just want to get the value of environment variables from dynamics 365 powerapps.

Is this meant to be a web resource ? It should be transpiled to JS in that case.

The term "environmental variable" has a specific meaning usually associated with unix systems. This has nothing to do with them AFAICT. I edited your question title and I strongly recommend editing your variable names in your code to avoid confusion, because you've already gotten an answer about actual envars.

If this is for a PCF, XRM is not available in a PCF control. You have to use the webAPI object available through the context
let results = await this.context.webAPI.retrieveMultipleRecords("environmentvariabledefinition",  '?$filter=schemaname eq '${name}'&$select=environmentvariabledefinitionid&$expand=environmentvariabledefinition_environmentvariablevalue($select=value)');

The documentation is available here.

Use process.env.VARIABLE_NAME.

OP does not appear to be actually asking about environmental variables.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
